# Cannot connect to a hosted NodeJS Git repository: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, server, linode

I'm not very experienced in hosting servers, so I apologize for any left out details; feel free to tell me what I'm missing and I'll provide it.

I'm using [cloud.linode.com](https://cloud.linode.com/) to host [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/HiTechFlufi/dewdrop-server). It's a Pokemon simulator that runs on JavaScript in NodeJS. I created a fork of the original website's repository and slapped it onto a cloud host; following the original Git's instructions for hosting your own copy of it, which really just consists of installing all of the necessary packages. Once I'm done, and I boot up the server, I can join it locally, but I cannot connect to it via the IP address Linode provides me, nor can any of my friends. I've also tried hosting it locally in a folder on my machine, starting it through the terminal, and port forwarding, or using a program such as `ngrok`, which gives you a link that redirects to your localhost website, allowing anyone to access it; same problem. I can join the server locally, with `localhost:8000`, but through the provided link or IP address, I get this error in Chrome:

[image]

I can't request an SSL certificate, as the link to connect to the server is just an IP address, not a domain. Notably, connecting to the server will **occasionally** work through the link/IP, but not typically. Sometimes, if you spam the "reload" button in your browser enough, or switch between browsers a few times, or try connecting in Incognito Mode, it will connect; but if you try again, it no longer will. It seems completely random and I cannot find any variable that correlates to it occasionally working, and then not immediately after. I'm in desperate need of help; again, let me know if there's any necessary information I've left out and I'll do my best to provide it. Thanks.

Comment: You say the link is just an IP address, but the screenshot shows a hostname (`23.92.19.98.psim.us`). Does the IP redirect traffic there?

Comment: @JimRedmond It does, yes. All server IPs and domains end in `.psim.us`. When you go to `23.92.19.98:8000`, it redirects you to `http://23.92.19.98.psim.us/`.

Comment: Then you do have a hostname - `23.92.19.98.psim.us`. Why can't you request a certificate for that hostname?

Comment: @JimRedmond Just tried using Certbot through the terminal in Debian. It gives me an error saying it's an unauthorized domain.

Comment: Requesting an SSL certificate requires information that's provided only when you register a domain, which I'm not doing for this process, it simply just generates me an IP.